# Unable to type Tibetan Monlam font in Pages and Microsoft Word 2019

Tags: macos, ms-office, pages, font

I am not able to type with the Tibetan Monlam boyig Unicode 2 font in Pages on macOS and Microsoft Word 2019.

I try to change English keyboard to Tibetan by pressing control - shift in my macbook pro (Mojave latest updated) pages and word 2019 both. But when I start to type, keyboard turned into English and English fonts appears

However it works well with InDesign CC 2019.

I am using macOS Mojave. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am using monlam boyig Unicode 2. As its font looks good. I try to change English keyboard to Tibetan by pressing control - shift in my macbook pro (Mojave latest updated) pages and word 2019 both. But when I start to type, keyboard turned into English and English fonts appears. Anyhow, monlam boyig Unicode 2 works well with InDesign and others. Help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

་I don't have any problem typing Tibetan characters in Pages with  Apple's Tibetan Qwerty Input Source and the font Monlam Uni Sans Serif, as shown below.  If you provide more info about your problem as requested in the comments, someone can probably help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am using monlam boyig Unicode 2. As its font looks good. I try to change English keyboard to Tibetan by pressing control - shift in my macbook pages and word 2019 both. But when I start to type, keyboard turned into English and English fonts appears. Help me, thanks.

Comment: @Tenzin Which input source are you using, Tibetan Qwerty, Tibetan Otani, or Tibetan Wylie?  Do you see the Tibetan icon in the flag menu at the top right of your screen when you start typing?  If you are using a Tibetan keyboard from a 3rd party, tell us the name.  Also, do you have the same problem when you are using the font Kailasa or Kokonor provided by Apple??

Comment: Hi Tom. I am using monlam bodyig 3 which third party software. This keyboard is too popular and fast to type.  I am not using apple's inbuilt keyboard, as its typing style is different. I tried apple provided keyboard and it works well but I don't want to use because its too hard to type. Second thing is that every time, I restart my computer the icon of the keyboard disappears and I have to add it again.

Comment: @Tenzin If Apple's keyboards work right, but the 3rd party one does not, then presumably the 3rd party software has a bug that needs fixing.  You should contact the people who made it and see if they can help.